# How to remove '../' tokens from a file path using the Visual Studio 2012 <filesystem> classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, filepath

I have a file path like 
`"C:/Documents/Music/Jazz/../../Pictures/picture.jpg"`.

I need to remove the '../' tokens and transform the original file path to `"C:/Documents/Pictures/picture.jpg"`.

How could I do that using the classes from Visual Studio 2012 (or 2013)  header?

Comment: Since when does C++11 standard filesystem library?

Comment: the what? where is it?

Comment: Sorry, It was my fault. Really, the <filesystem> header provided with Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 has not become a part of the C++ standard. I'll then edit the question.

Comment: Its okay, but it could be important to know whether we were talking about `boost::filesystem` v2 or v3, as the standard will probably be based on v3, while VS's header is based on v2.

Comment: Since I refer to VS 2012 <filesystem> header, we are talking about the  boost::filesystem v2

Answer (score 3):

C++11 does not have a filesystem library. This is considered for the [C++14 or C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3399.html) standards.

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) has a filesystem api, [boost:filesystem:path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) is what you might want to look at.

Comment: so it seems that what he wants is `boost::filesystem::canonical(boost::filesystem::path("C:\path\..\here\is\..\"));` or in C++17 `std::filesystem::canonical(boost::filesystem::path("C:\path\..\here\is\..\"));` the resulting `path` object has overloaded conversions to string.

Comment: Brilliant discovery, PeterT! However, I'd like to find a way to do the task without boost.

Comment: @DmitrySapelnikov why you cannot just erase from std::string?

Answer (score 1):

C++ 11 doesn't have a filesystem library.

However it does have a algorithm library and string library which will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 doesn't contain filesystem library. You can work with your path using standard facilities offered by `std::string`:

```
std::string s("C:/Documents/Music/Jazz/../../Pictures/picture.jpg");
size_t t;
while ( (t = s.find( "/..")) != std::string::npos) {
    s.erase( t, 3);
}
if ( (t = s.find( "/Music/Jazz")) != std::string::npos) {
    s.erase( t, 11);
}
```